# Unable to generate constant date formatting vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue where dates are generated in completely different ways that have caused error. These errors include years being classified as days and vice versa. It is taking dates formatted as 07-JUN-17 and selecting the first two values as year and last value 17 as day. Additionally First Date read is not overwritten comes out as 2018-1-1 so it is completely different. Any suggestions on how to change to create common date format?

```
YearA = Range("YearA").Value + 0
FirstDateRead = DateSerial(YearA + 1, 1, 1)  'Initialize the first Day of the year as the last day
LastDateRead = DateSerial(YearA, 1, 1)       'Initialize the last Day of the year as the first day
FirstDateBill = DateSerial(YearA + 1, 1, 1)  'Initialize the first Day of the year as the last day
LastDateBill = DateSerial(YearA, 1, 1)       'Initialize the last Day of the year as 

       'FirstDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 5).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 5).Value = Format(FirstDateBill, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'LastDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 6).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 6).Value = Format(LastDateBill, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'FirstDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 7).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 7).Value = Format(FirstDateRead, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'LastDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 8).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 8).Value = Format(LastDateRead, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'ProratedDays
```

Comment: *It is taking dates* **formatted** *as* - I would check the actual input values (actual text values) that you are working with. Problem occurs most likely in the data inside the cell (not the format mask of the data).

Answer (score 1):

Format(FirstDateBill, "dd-MMM-yy") turns the date into a string of characters
"01-jan-xx" (where xx is dependent on range("yearA")

When you assign that to the cell Report.Cells(LineNum, 5), Excel attempts to convert that string into a value using its internal (American) date converter. But you had already converted it to a date before - so stop turning it into a string

```
Report.Cells(LineNum, 5).Value =  FirstDateBill
```

will work fine.